# How do I select a data every second with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a SQL query that selects every data between two dates and now I would like to add the time scale factor so that instead of returning all the data it returns one data every second, minute or hour.

Do you know how I can achieve it ?

My query :

`"SELECT received_on, $1 FROM $2 WHERE $3 <= received_on AND received_on <= $4", [data_selected, table_name, date_1, date_2]`

The table input:

[image: Table Input]

As you can see there are several data the same second, I would like to select only one per second

Comment: Could you share a sample of the input table and the expected output?

Comment: For sure, Tell me if this is clearer? @Ahmed

Comment: What row should be selected, i.e. adc_v with max, min, first or last value

Comment: Any row, but let's say adc_v

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your table data as formatted text into your request instead.

Comment: I will try to better formulate my question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are several rows per second, and you only want one result row per second, you can decide to pick one of the rows for each second. This can be a randomly chosen row or you pick the row with the greatest or least value in a column as shown in Ahmed's answer.

It would be more typical, though, to aggregate your data per second. The columns show figures and you are interested in those figures. Your sample data shows two times the value 2509 and three times the value 2510 for the adc_v column at 2022-07-29, 15:52. Consider what you would like to see. Maybe you don't want this value go below some boundary, so you show the minimum value `MIN(adc_v)` to see how low it went in the second. Or you want to see the value that occured most often in the second `MODE(adc_v)`. Or you'd like to see the average value `AVG(adc_v)`. Make this decision for every value, so as to get the informarion most vital to you.

```
select
  received_on,
  min(adc_v),
  avg(adc_i),
  ...
from mytable
group by received_on
order by received_on;
```

If you want this for another interval, say an hour instead of the month, truncate your received_on column accordingly. E.g.:

```
select
  date_trunc('hour', received_on) as received_hour,
  min(adc_v),
  avg(adc_i),
  ...
from mytable
group by date_trunc('hour', received_on)
order by date_trunc('hour', received_on);
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, I understand better now thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select data every second, you may use `ROW_NUMBER()` function partitioned by 'received_on' as the following:

```
WITH DateGroups AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY received_on ORDER BY adc_v) AS rn
  FROM table_name
)
SELECT received_on, adc_v, adc_i, acc_axe_x, acc_axe_y, acc_axe_z 
FROM DateGroups
WHERE rn=1 
ORDER BY received_on
```

If you want to select data every minute or hour, you may use the extract function to get the number of seconds in 'received_on' and divide it by 60 to get the minutes or divide it by 3600 to get the hours.

> epoch: For date and timestamp values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00-00 (can be negative); for interval values, the total number of seconds in the interval

Group by minutes:

```
WITH DateGroups AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY floor(extract(epoch from (received_on)) / 60) ORDER BY adc_v) AS rn
  FROM table_name
)
SELECT received_on, adc_v, adc_i, acc_axe_x, acc_axe_y, acc_axe_z 
FROM DateGroups
WHERE rn=1  
ORDER BY received_on
```

Group by hours:

```
WITH DateGroups AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY floor(extract(epoch from (received_on)) / (60*60)) ORDER BY adc_v) AS rn
  FROM table_name
)
SELECT received_on, adc_v, adc_i, acc_axe_x, acc_axe_y, acc_axe_z 
FROM DateGroups
WHERE rn=1  
ORDER BY received_on
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/eSGLK_a7).

Comment: You should add an `ORDER BY received_on` to the queries, if you want don't want the result rows in arbitrary order.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I'll update the answer according to this. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, so far it doesn't seem to work on my table. My query selects the data of each date (5 per second), Can you explain me what 'rn' is ?

Comment: rn is the row number partitioned by the specified group (second, minute, hour) ordered by adc_v in ascending order, so this query will return the rows with a minimum value of 'adc_v' for each group. [check this](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/sql-tutorial/row-number-funtion-in-sql) for more details about using row_number function.